# I'm trying to deploy a smart contract on Goerli, but receiving an ImportError

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, brownie

I'm deploying a contract on Goerli using Brownie, following all the steps of the guide correctly, I've compiled contract 'FundMe' successfully but it returns an error - **ImportError: cannot import name 'FundMe' from 'brownie'**.

I'm using a command - `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network goerli`. Also .yaml file is correct and solidity file is in Contracts directory (actual problem for others was that they had solidity file in build/contracts directory).

This is the deploy.py file:

```
def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
    print(f"Contractt deployed to {fund_me.address}")

def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before. It's like due to the `Fundme` was not loaded. The workaround was to use `brownie console` instead of the deploy script.

In your case, try:

1. `cd` to your project path
2. run `brownie console --network goerli`, then `FundMe` should be loaded as a variable.
3. run `accounts.add('YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY')`, replace `YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY` with your private key.
4. run `fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": accounts[0]})`, then wait for a sec. The contract should be deployed.

Then you can interact with the contract using `fund_me.ANY_FUNCTION()`, replace `ANY_FUNCTION()` with your function.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. The problem was that solidity file name was FundMe.sol and inside that file the contract name was funMe, so I was importing from brownie FundMe instead of fundMe and that was the problem <3